# does winrt have a gesture builder

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, gesture

In the android world there is a cool utility called [Gesture Builder](http://android-coding.blogspot.ca/2011/09/gestures-builder-create-your-gestures.html) that allows you to associate a pre-recorded gesture with a command.  For example, they can do an X on the screen and it would close the app, or draw a heart and have the app send a valentine email.

Is there a similar feature with WinRT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is anything built in, but you could try $1, N$ - One Dollar and N Dollar Recognizers:

- http://depts.washington.edu/aimgroup/proj/dollar/
- http://depts.washington.edu/aimgroup/proj/dollar/ndollar.html
- http://blogs.claritycon.com/kevinmarshall/2008/11/21/beginning-multi-touch-on-windows-7-amp-basic-gesture-recognition/
- http://employees.claritycon.com/kmarshall/DollarMultiTouch.zip

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly what you want but may be helpful Windows.UI.Input.GestureRecognizer.