# How Do I recognize basic shapes with Ink and WinRT

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, shapes, microsoft.ink

Is there a simple way to get shape recognition working with WinRT?
With WPF it was simple I could just use InkAnalysis but it seems that it is not available in WinRT(?).
I want to be able to draw basic shapes circle, rectangle and square and I want to be able to recognize them.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The [GestureRecognizer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/BR241937) class that you get out of the box only supports the simple gestures used in various standard Windows 8 controls. For your scenario you could try the 1$/n$ recognizers I linked to in [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13731996/does-winrt-have-a-gesture-builder).